# opencv and javacv compatibility issue

Tags: java, opencv

I had used opencv 2.4.6 and javacv 0.6 in past. Now after changing the version of opencv from 2.4.6 to 2.4.9 and keeping the javacv version same, i get the below error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\kedar.parikh\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp68881190092600\jniopencv_highgui.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

what could be the issue ?

Comment: i doesn't have an answer but an idea. use dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check which dll's are needed. Maybe this gives more info for further research

Comment: you probably should use [opencv's own java bindings](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d9/d52/tutorial_java_dev_intro.html), not the outdated 3rd party javacv ones